# How to run multiple sql statements in Postgres using the tool PGADMIN?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

I have 170 Alter Drop Constraint statement, 120 Truncate table, 120 Insert table and 170 Alter Add Constraint.
All of these should be run in one in one script as batch script and I'm using PGADMIN IV tool.

Tried executing them between Begin and End as follows like Oracle,

```
BEGIN 
ALTER Statement1..,,
ALTER Statement2..,,
TRUNCATE Statement3..,,
TRUNCATE Statement4..,,
INSERT Statement5..,,
INSERT Statement6..,,
ALTER Statement7..,,
ALTER Statement8..,,
---
-----
-------
---------
END;
```

But its not working,

Can some one please give a suggestion on how I can do this?

Comment: Please try `BEGIN;  statement1; statement2;  END;` [doc in here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/tutorial-transactions.html)